# Removing unassigned unicode encodes from text files

Tags: linux, unicode, awk, sed

We receive text files from numerous sources with varied and unidentified encodes and have to make them utf8 Unicode compliant (pleas don't ask why...politics).  This means replacing or removing unassigned encodes.  To make things worse we can only use Linux commands or routines such as grep, awk, sed, etc.  We have tried using iconv but cannot make it work on only unassigned encodes. We cannot use perl, python, c, etc. (no supporting staff). Currently we are using the following command to isolate the line number of the offending string but have failed to be able to isolate, change, and/or remove the unassigned characters:

```
grep -HPn '\p{Cn}' {filename}| cut -f1-2 -d: >> utfmsg.txt
```

Again the problem is how to pluck out only unassigned utf8 encodes.  All of our other attempts strip out more than unassigned values.

Comment: You're basically trying to solve a programming problem without a programming language. Good luck.

Comment: Does the `iconv` `//IGNORE` modifier not work? As in `iconv --from-code utf8 --to-code utf8//IGNORE`? The manual page I have for `iconv` states that, when given this option, "characters that cannot be represented in the target character set will be silently discarded.".

Comment: Unfortunately we have tried your above suggestions. For some unknown reason iconv will not translate or ignore the offending character.  One particular character is represented in hex by 'F09F9884'x but there are others.  currently we use grep to find the line containing the character and then manually delete the character using xemacs or other editor.

Comment: It's hard to understand exactly what it is you want to do... Are you saying that you want to go through a text file and find anything that isn't a valid UTF-8 byte sequence and then remove bytes one by one until it's valid?  Or try to guess the encoding of the text file and convert it to UTF-8?

Comment: Or, since hex F0 9F 98 84 *is* a valid UTF-8 byte sequence (It's 'SMILING FACE WITH OPEN MOUTH AND SMILING EYES' U+1F604) http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f604/index.htm - maybe you're asking for something else entirely, like removing some unicode characters you don't like?